# How can I include third party DLL's for ClickOnce deployment in a VS2012 application?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, sql-server-ce

I've been struggling with this for days and cannot piece this together.  I have an application that includes:

1. a main module written in C#
2. a support module written in C++ as a managed class library
3. third party native DLL's
4. the DLL's for SQL Server Compact Edition 4.

Currently, all the DLL's are in the main folder of the main module which creates a mess of files in a single, flat  directory.  This works, but it is far from elegant.  Here is what I would like to do:

```
--> (Main Module Directory) <--
    Main Module (C#)
    -->Libs (subdirectory under main module) <--
       C++ Managed Class Library
       SQL CE 4.0 DLLs
       Third Party DLLs
```

I really want to clean up the folder structure in VS2012 when I'm working on the project.  These files can all be in the Main Module Directory when the application is deployed.  I've tried a post build script which moves the files; however, they are not included in the ClickOnce package after they have been moved.

What complicates this is the calling order of the modules.  It is as follows:

1. Main Module calls SQL CE4.0 DLLs
2. Main Modules calls C++ Class Library
3. Class Library calls Third Party native DLL's.  (I'm not using DLImport.  I have the lib files so they are called with `extern "C"`.

I tried creating a configuration file and using `<probing>` with no luck.  My guess is `<probing>` applies only to the Main Module in C#. The main module never calls the third party DLL's directly.

Comment: I have some tips on probing (and other tips on private deployment on my blog also) http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2011/06/sql-server-compact-private-deployment.html - do you compile for x86? (recommended)

Comment: With the comment from Erik, I have a solution for this.  Thank you for the blog post.